# How to apply theme to Drupal view or block

Tags: views

I have created 1 view for displaying Category on home page using Ubercart module.

but i want to apply custom css  changes to my Category view fields like image and title

can any knows how to apply css change to DRUPAL views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify - in title you are talking about themes, in body about CSS rules, so what's your real need?

Comment: hi, i have created 1 view for Product Category . so i want to apply css like <div> tag and class etc to my view which displays Category Image and name.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your view display and look at the bottom of the "advanced" column. You'll see something like "Theme : Information". Try to locate your template name and click on it to get it's base code.

Comment: yes, i have seen it , but if i want to add my <div> tag or class in that file then where to place that file , can you tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

[Block Class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) module allows you to assign arbitrary classes to your blocks. You can use it in CSS selectors without manually rewriting tpl.php files.