# Drupal 8 Apply Custom Theme To View

Tags: views, theming

I have a Drupal 8 installation set up that is using a custom Bootstrap theme as the default theme. I have a View created to be a blog, and want to give it a different custom theme than the default. I have the path set as "/blog". Is there a simple way of doing this through code (specifically referencing either the URL or the view) or a menu option I've overlooked?

I've looked at other related questions on here such as: [How to apply theme to Drupal view or block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73244/how-to-apply-theme-to-drupal-view-or-block/73245#73245?newreg=54e3f33bd3c24d0ab5754ad617acb170)

But in my View display settings there is no "Theme : Information" option available.

Any help is greatly appreciated! If there is more details I can provide for a solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 8 views doesn't have a Theme: Information section, or at least it doesn't have information about themes.

Twig is the themeing engine, so you'll need to get information there. You can enable twig debugging in a `services.yml` file:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

This will print out theme-able names for views in the html. On a site I'm looking at the print out only gives one option for the view:

```
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/sitename/templates/block--views-block--our-leadership-senior-management.html.twig' -->
```

But the block that holds the view has a number of options:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
x block--views-block--our-leadership-senior-management.html.twig
* block--views-block.html.twig
* block--views.html.twig
* block.html.twig
-->
```

The `x` indicates that's the template I'm using.

Comment: So I looked into what you mentioned and I was able to get drupal to start pulling a different twig template. The issue now is that its only pulling the twig template from my default theme (bootstrap) but I'm trying to get it to pull a template from a different non-default theme. Any recommendations for how to go about that?

Comment: I've seen this done with the rules module, pretty easy and quick. Or you could write a custom module that sets the active theme based on the url.

Comment: I was able to use the Theme Negotiator in one of my custom modules and it seems to be working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!